# JPEGImageEncoder don't work in JDK 7

Tags: java, jcaptcha

I try to make captcha using JCaptcha Component and i need to encode image in related servlet. So according to JCaptcha Tutorial, I should use JPEGImageEncoder and it's not compatible with JDK7.
What else can i do?
here is related part of code:

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream jpegOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     BufferedImage challenge =
             CaptchaServiceSingleton.getInstance().getImageChallengeForID(captchaId,
                     httpServletRequest.getLocale());
   JPEGImageEncoder jpegEncoder =
                 JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(jpegOutputStream);
         jpegEncoder.encode(challenge);
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
         return;
     } catch (CaptchaServiceException e) {
         httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
         return;
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

```
ImageWriter imageWriter = 
    ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
ImageOutputStream ios = 
    ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(jpegOutputStream);
imageWriter.setOutput(ios);
IIOMetadata imageMetaData = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(
    new ImageTypeSpecifier(challenge), null);
imageWriter.write(
    imageMetaData, new IIOImage(challenge, null, null), null);
```

This replaces the internal and deprecated JPEG functions.